# how to create flip page application in iphone

Tags: iphone

I want to create flip page application. in this application take input as a pdf and then after i want to convert that pdf in to flip page application. Please give me hint.

Comment: What is your question? How to load PDFs into your application bundle? How to read PDFs? How to display them? Your question is too vague.

Comment: I am able to parse content of pdf. I am able to display pdf page as a image image in scroll view. but pdf page is cut when width is more than scroll view. I want to display pdf whole page without lost its quality.

Answer (score 2):

To do a page flip effect you may:

- play with Cocoa touch framework and its [UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp/Down](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) transitions
- use cocos2d framework which supports a 'one-side' page transition (see [CCPageTurn3D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.9.0-alpha/interface_c_c_page_turn3_d.html))
- make your own code ([Implementing 2D Page Flip effect on iPhone OS](http://nomtek.com/developers/page-flip-2d/) is a good point to start from)
- for 3D page flip effect you can read [Adding 3rd dimension to the page flip effect on iPhone OS](http://nomtek.com/tips-for-developers/page-flip-3d/).

Answer (score 2):

iOS 4

This will handle page flip image or pdf... https://github.com/ole/leaves/tree/twopages

iOS 5 and up

[UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPageViewController)